# COVID-19 Case Line Data Sources for US States

Tags: covid19, epidemic

The state of Florida provides detailed information of each positive case in its jurisdiction.

https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/FDOH::florida-covid19-case-line-data/data

which allows a more detailed analysis of hospitalization/icu/ventilation/fatality rates at the age level.

Is anyone aware of other states or similar dataset structure for other administrative units in America or around the world?

Below is the State of Florida's Case Line Data Definition Table for reference:
[image: State of Florida's Case Line Data Definition Table]

Comment: can you provide more information about Case Line data please? I think it would be helpful; I see/work with a lot of COVID19 data daily, I'm just completely unfamiliar with the term. And that Repository's data dictionary/definition is lacking. Sorry/thanks.

Comment: You should reach out to the FL dept that manages the information for the definitions. All I see is the same data you see. (Metadata >  https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=37abda537d17458bae6677b8ab75fcb9 )